# Black Screen on boot fresh install 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, screen

Ive looked around and can't find an answer to my question. I just installed Lubuntu with a live USB and now when i try to boot the only thing i get is a black screen it appears its working but i cant see anything. I had to fix this same problem when trying to boot into try Lubuntu without installing and to fix that i had to change some parameters like nomodeset and xforcevesa. Is there a similar fix to my problem? I am sorta tech savy but new to Linux in general so any help is appreciated in advance.

GPU - 750 ti
CPU - i7 - 4790k

edit - Holding shift does not enter grub either i tried
thanks J. Steen

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) question: if you can't enter `grub` using `Right Shift` use `ESC` instead

Answer (score 1):

Your GRUB has been mistakenly installed on your USB stick. If you plug in your USB and restart it should work. To fix this, I used to remove the USB stick during installation when the GRUB settings popped up, went one step back then continued from there.